# How to make shortcut on android launcher for hybrid app?

Tags: android, shortcut, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to make it easy to add website shortcut to home screen by pressing a button. So What I am Thinking is a button at the bottom of my hybrid app that says "Add to home screen ? yes or no" and when "yes" pressed, it adds the shortcut to the home screen without closing the application. what code should I add To do that?

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that creates a web browser shortcut:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Goto http://www.example.com/link");
Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.shortcut_icon);
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/link")));
sendBroadcast(shortcutIntent);
```

here is the permission you need to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer! and.. i want webside code too.. how can i pass web oreder onto android..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. In the code above just replace `http://www.example.com/link` with your link

Comment: hmm... i developing hybrid app, so i need android code and JSP code. if i send command to android from JSP, What do i use JSP code